# Not receiving Push Notifications Using firebase Then Application in Backgorund

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FireBase Notification not receiving then my application in background mode 
my project add entitlements and project Compatibility Push notification 'ON' Background Mode Remote Notification 'ON' Every Thing Configure
In Foreground Mode receive notification with this data

```
2017-02-12 12:34:51.149420 NBC[1537:332542] Connected to FCM.
2017-02-12 12:34:51.169958 NBC[1537:332542] {
     "collapse_key" = "ae.nationalbonds.ios";
     from = 232579403465;
       notification =     {
           badge = 2;
           body = Test;
             e = 1;
            sound = default;
           sound2 = default;
     };
   }


> if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
            // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            }];

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
#endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        // [END register_for_notifications]
    }

    // [START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]
    // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
```